# Book about a mysterious girl and evil non-human pursuers

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Some elements that I remember:

- Bluey-green cover with a medallion on it
- Almost certainly set in London
- Half of [city] is semi-abandoned, maybe partially flooded?
- Begins with protagonist tracking/hunting an imp or jackal-like that has been stealing children
- Protagonist is navigating/tracking by placing milk in a bowl of blood
- At some point, protagonist (and friends) stumble upon and rescue a girl who is essentially feral
- I remember one of the type of baddies chasing her were described as things from the ocean, and they made the air cold, clammy and salty when they arrived in the night

I got this book from the library when I was young - which would be around 10 years ago, give or take - and forgot the name and author, but the feeling of it stuck with me and I have been struggling to identify it ever since.

Any pointers - even just how I might better search for it myself - would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was the main protagonist male/female? Were they adults? Did the book seem to be aimed at any particular age group?

Comment: Was the medallion part of the cover art, or something added? The Newbery and Caldecott awards for children's books are medals, often added to a book's cover as a printed or foil overlay.

Comment: The main (first, at least) protagonist was a male adult, and I'd say it was young-adult or teen fiction... I read it in 2002, so I'd have been 12.

Medallion was part of the cover art, I believe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is 'The Haunting of Alaizabel Cray'?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haunting_of_Alaizabel_Cray

It has a medallion on the cover anyway...

Comment: This sounds very like it, though the tracking method is a bead of sulpher in a bowl of pig's blood rather than a drop of blood in a bowl of milk.

Comment: Aha, that is it! Have you read it? If not, how did you know? I cannot thank you enough :)!

Comment: I can't believe I've (thanks to you) finally found it again, aaahhhh

Comment: I did read it, and liked it.  A bit surprised to see it has its own Wikipedia entry though - obviously we're not the only ones who rate it.